# woocommerce: Removing product attributes write panel tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

have successfully removed all product write panel tabs except "attributes" using the code from this post "WooCommerce: Removing product write panel tab"

`function remove_linked_products($tabs){
    unset($tabs['linked_product']);
    return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_linked_products', 10, 1);`

how can i remove attributes tab and add attributes toolbar.

Thank you
ucarman

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here, maybe you might want to try rewording the question?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are unsetting `attributes` instead of `attribute`? The following code works just fine for me:

```
function remove_linked_products($tabs){
    unset($tabs['attribute']);
    return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_linked_products', 10, 1);
```